# spark dataframe groupby and distinct not producing expected results

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

spark dataframe groupby and distinct are not producing expected results I expect... not sure its the characters in my strings that are causing the problem.

```
scala> df.select(df("ID")).distinct.show(false)
2018-05-25 17:17:29 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Stage 68 contains a task of very large size (556 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
+------------------------------------+
|ID                                  |
+------------------------------------+
|2445b371-7cec-41b0-947a-8a04c4e8cbbb|
|db33c6d4-26fb-42c8-99a3-1bdfc2bf4612|
+------------------------------------+
```

Which doesn't make sense since those strings are not in the dataset...

```
scala> df.select(df("ID")).show(false)
2018-05-25 17:17:50 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Stage 79 contains a task of very large size (556 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
+------------------------------------+
|ID                                  |
+------------------------------------+
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
|80a9d91d-c66f-4bf7-89a0-acf9ccd8e1b8|
+------------------------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The type is a simple string

```
scala> df.select(df("ID")).printSchema
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: you selected ID but in your printSchema why do you have matchID instead of ID?

Comment: typo, fixed thanks

Comment: try `df.select(df("ID")).where(df("ID") === "2445b371-7cec-41b0-947a-8a04c4e8cbbb").show(false)` you should see output. meaning that there should be records with 2445b371-7cec-41b0-947a-8a04c4e8cbbb as ID

Comment: Ramesh, without even trying I believe that would work this example case. unfortunately, I'm interested in why in this case distinct doesn't work, so that generalization is possible.

Comment: Why are you assuming that distinct is not working properly?

Comment: in the example above I show it working on the identical Data.. yet it shows two groups both do not exist in the data. for example purposes I had only one Id. I'm going to redo everything this morning and see if u was smoking crack that day or not.

Comment: how do you know that 2445b371-7cec-41b0-947a-8a04c4e8cbbb id is not present in data? thats what I told you to confirm by doing `df.select(df("ID")).where(df("ID") === "2445b371-7cec-41b0-947a-8a04c4e8cbbb").show(false)` but you said it will work. so it means that the id is present in the dataset. isn't it